# BASH paste sourced files into main source

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a fairly large BASH project, which I split into multiple files to make it more readable. As a result, the main file contains many `source` statements.

Now I'm releasing it on GitHub and I'm writing an installer script for it. The problem is that creating subdirectories under binary folders (exactly `/usr/local/sbin`) is prohibited by the FHS and I don't want to mess up binary folders with several files like `main.bash` `config.bash`, etc.

As a solution, I thought that if the installer script would merge together these files, I'd get a large, monolithic BASH file, which can be put anywhere on the system.

The question is: how can I substitute all `source` statements in my main script with the contents of the sourced files?

Example:

**included.bash**

```
echo "bar"
```

**main.bash**

```
echo "foo"
source included.bash
```

**Resulting monolithic file**

```
echo "foo"
echo "bar"
```

Comment: Why not in `/usr/local/lib/<yourprogramname>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script, which might be called `make-monolithic.bash`, will walk through each line in `main.bash` and look for a `source` statement. If there's no match it will just copy that line to the `monolithic.bash` file. However if a `source` line is found, the filename is extracted and the contents of that file will be copied to `monolithic.bash`, instead of the original `source` line.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly MAIN="main.bash"
readonly MONOLITHIC="monolithic.bash"

[ -f "$MONOLITHIC" ] && cp "$MONOLITHIC" "${MONOLITHIC}.bak"

## to extract sourced filename
regex='^\([[:space:]]*\)source[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]*$'

IFS=$'\n'  ## retain whitespace

while read main_line; do
    sourced=$(echo "$main_line" | sed -n "s/$regex/\2/p")
    if [ -n "$sourced" ]; then
        indent=$(echo "$main_line" | sed -n "s/$regex/\1/p")
        while read sourced_line; do
            echo "${indent}${sourced_line}" >> "$MONOLITHIC"
        done < "$sourced"
    else
        echo "$main_line" >> "$MONOLITHIC"
    fi
done < "$MAIN"

unset IFS

[ -f "${MONOLITHIC}.bak" ] && rm "${MONOLITHIC}.bak"
```

- tested on your provided example
- also gracefully ignores possible whitespace issues in the `source` line
- plus: automatically applies the same amount of indentation to the contents of the sourced file as found before the `source` statement (none, if `source` line was not indented, as in your example)